# Can i configure maven to use custom build number for Snapshot version

Tags: maven, maven-metadata

If i am deploying a snapshot jar file using mvn deploy, then maven generates the jar file name depending based as follows

```
projectname-1.0-20170509.204524-1.jar
```

That is

```
$project1-$version-$date.$time-$buildnumber.jar
```

Can i configure maven to use custom jar file name?

```
Eg projectname-1.0-1.jar, projectname-1.0-2.jar
```

Comment: Simple answer No. The question what kind of problem are you trying to solve here?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the artifact's version is a snapshot. Snapshot artifacts (since Maven 3.x) always must have a timestamped version.

You should not be changing this.

If, you would like to change it for purposes other than for deploying to an artifact repository, I believe you can do this via the `finalName`, or via the `maven-assembly-plugin`.

Either way, this is (usually) a very bad idea.